# How can I add a menu to an executable file that does not have one?

Tags: exe

I am just reverse-engineering an application I made for fun but since it doesn't have a menu. How can I add one?

I tried using IDA pro but no hope, same with OllyDbg.

Answer (score 1):

If exe supports plugins or uses dll - you can

- use plugin functionality
- or make proxy-dll with required functionality.

or, find a free space in the executable and write a **patch** that adds a
menu to your application.

useful WinAPI functions:
**CreateMenu**, **AppendMenu**, **InsertMenuItem**

**to Author**,

here we discuss reverse engineering, not programming or hacking

Comment: Can you write down the code for the patch. Thanks!